# what are some best practices for maven artifact naming when multiple code branches exist?

Tags: maven, artifact

Suppose we have an app that's being developed on trunk and a couple of branches simultaneously - and we'd like to publish artifacts from each dev branch into our maven repo (so that we can run a cluster for each code branch). Currently the 'V' in GAV equals our CI's build plan execution number.

What are some approaches for differentiating GAVs between each code branch? I can think of:

- using different artifact names (ie `myapp` for trunk, `myapp-b1` for branch1 version, etc)
- reset version numbers so that trunk's starts at 100, branch 1 starts at 10,000, etc (unlikely to collide in our case but seems cheesy)

Answer (score 0):

I think the best practice here is to use timestamps as suffix for version numbers, e.g.
`4.3.20150415171925255`. This means it is 4th major version, 3rd minor and artifact produced on `2015-04-15T17:19:25.255`.

Thanks to that convention you should avoid naming conflicts and you always know which is the newest version.

Comment: Don't think that works here - since each dev branch produces a different artifact. Therefore, it does not matter whether artifact from branch1 is newer or older than artifact from branch2. the intent is to deploy latest versions of each artifacts in a separate cluster. What you're describing is implemented by maven for X-SNAPSHOT versions already